# In Android, I am not able to access a TextView( which is in MainActivity) from a different class

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Not sure what is going wrong..
What I am trying to do is inflate a textView which is available in `MainActivity` into a different class (non activity). I am actually not getting any error but it simply does not show the text that is shown below after execution. Any suggestion will definitely be appreciated.

```
protected void onPreExecute(){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null,false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText("you great really!");

}
```

Comment: hi, kindly put more code, i recommend that you attach your full code

Comment: hii @subha , to access the textView of main activity you can get the reference like this and update the text.  textView = (TextView) ((MainActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.invalidate();
```

after setText();

or if not happened allready of course adding it to the view heirarchy respectiyely to the layout view you are using for content in activity